# Remove HttpPage Extension in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I want to remove Http Page Extension like this

my actual page:
http://test.com/dashboard.aspx

i need to modify as follows
http://test.com/

for all redirection of .aspx page.

P.s:
i dont want to use URL rewriting.

Comment: you need to mark right answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write **HttpModule** where you can scan incoming url and make all that you want before request will be processed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use asp.net 4's routing engine. You can specify a routing rule in asp.net 4 as a default route. 
Check out:
http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Default-Route-in-ASPNET-4-URL-Routing.aspx

for a very basic one that may work in your scenario try this in your global.asax.cs to map everything to say default.aspx

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{*whatever}", "~/default.aspx");
    }
```